# How to tier iOS IAPs

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

For our app there is the option to buy in app points, ranging from 800-16,000 points. The cost for these points goes from $0.99-$19.99 in steps of $1. Is it possible to tier an in app purchase like this so I don't have to create 20 different In-App Purchases in App Store Connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you can automate in App Store Connect are listed here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi

If you don't see creation of in app purchases there, you cannot automate your in app purchase creation at all. So since you have 20 purchasables you will have to create 20 in app purchases, manually.

Comment: Pain! I guess it is what it is